# how to use typeahead with smarttable?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead, smart-table

I have created a smarttable combined with a typeahead functionality:

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-click="selectPerson()" ng-model="selectedPerson"
           bs-options="person.firstName for person in rowCollection" placeholder="Search for person" bs-typeahead>

    <table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
            <th st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
            <th st-sort="birthDate">birth date</th>
            <th st-sort="balance">balance</th>
        </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
            <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.birthDate}}</td>
            <td>{{row.balance}}</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" ng-click="removeItem(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">
                    </i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The goal is to search for a person in the table in the search input ,select the name and then display in the smarttable below it. When I select a person this fires:

```
$scope.selectPerson = function(){
    $scope.displayedCollection = $scope.selectedPerson;
    console.log($scope.displayedCollection );
}
```

It does not display the person in the table however. How can I fix it so it displays the person?

plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/NXEbl5?p=preview